# How to use distribution provisioning profile with Fabric?

Tags: ios, push-notification, provisioning-profile, fabric.io

I want to upload an iOS app build with [Fabric](https://fabric.io/) app which will use production Apple push notifications environment. For this I think the build should use a distribution (Ad Hoc) provisioning profile (I've read this: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/provisioning-profiles.html).
I use "Automatically manage signing" feature. When I archive and try to upload the build to Fabric, the Fabric app says "Dev. profile: iOS Team Provision...". How to use a distribution (Ad Hoc) provisioning profile instead while using automatic signing? I can make it work with manual signing, but I'm wondering if it's possible with automatic signing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a particular provisioning profile with the particular scheme you have to do a manual signing. You can do a few schemes and assign each provisioning profile for them. I prefer to do Debug, Release (using the development provisioning profile), AdHoc and AppStore schemes.

Comment: Thanks. So I understand it's mandatory to use manual signing if I want to use distribution (instead of development) provisioning profile for builds uploaded to Fabric.